# Djangoitem in scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy

Hi i typed in the command

```
from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem
```

in the scrapy shell and it gave me the following error.

```
In [1]: from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/abhishek/<ipython-input-1-3b57a31ce938> in <module>()
----> 1 from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem

ImportError: No module named djangoitem
```

What would have been the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to rule it out, does that import work from the Python interpreter?

Comment: Hi. No it does not work with python interpreter either!

Comment: Is there a problem with your path perhaps?

Comment: I reinstalled scrapy and the error was gone. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it solved.

For some reason `pip-install` did not actually install all the directories that come with scrapy. The `djangoitem` was not being installed.

I used `easy_install` to reinstall scrapy and the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

It is an external package

```
pip install scrapy-djangoitem
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now moved to another package called `scrapy_djangoitem`

See more here:

- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/djangoitem.html
- https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem